# R: Cut function with POSIXct dates: Creating specific categories based on time of day

Tags: r, cut, posixct

I have a small training set of data that I am beginning to analyze. The dataset is comprised of hospital procedural codes, values for said procedure, and a date/time stamp. I am attempting to break down the time stamps into 'time of day' categories, as some of the procedural values will vary depending on morning/evening.

I have tried using `cut()`, but I can't seem to figure out how to input specific time intervals for the categories (ex. 00:00 to 06:00 = "Fasting", 06:01- 10:00 = "Morning Meal", ...).

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide a code example of what you've tried

Comment: `x_cut<- cut(x$servicedate, 4)` returns a breakdown of the data into four categorical intervals across the year of data. I am hoping to specifically categorize the procedural values by time of day, not 4 intervals across the year.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the hour from the date using `hour` in package lubridate.

```
> library(lubridate)
> now()
[1] "2016-04-26 23:21:56 CEST"
> dt <- now()
> hour(dt)
[1] 23
> cut(hour(dt), breaks = c(0, 6, 12, 18, 24), include.lowest = TRUE)
[1] (18,24]
Levels: [0,6] (6,12] (12,18] (18,24]>
```

Comment: No need for a package for a simple task like this - `cut(as.integer(format(x, "%H")), seq(0,24,6), include.lowest=TRUE )`

Comment: Sure, no need to use lubridate, but I think it makes the code easier to understand and it avoids the `as.integer` step