# Organizing time data into constant time intervals

Tags: r

I'm working with a large data set with complete date and time in                   '2018-04-06 14:39:00' format. I am trying to create a new column in the data frame that has the individual time intervals of each timestamp into quarters of a day such as:

```
"00:00 - 05:59"
"06:00 - 11:59"
"12:00 - 17:59"
"18:00 - 23:59"
```

For example, timestamp of "5:00" will have time interval of "00:00 - 05:59" located in another column of the same respective row of that timestamp in the data frame.

```
> dput(file1[, c("V8", "V9")])

structure(list(V8 = structure(1:19, .Label = c("4/6/2018 14:39", 
"4/6/2018 15:04", "4/6/2018 15:09", "4/6/2018 15:28", "4/6/2018 15:56", 
"4/6/2018 16:02", "4/6/2018 16:07", "4/6/2018 16:10", "4/6/2018 16:11", 
"4/6/2018 16:27", "4/6/2018 16:41", "4/6/2018 16:43", "4/6/2018 16:57", 
"4/6/2018 17:13", "4/6/2018 17:17", "4/6/2018 17:30", "4/6/2018 17:38", 
"4/6/2018 17:47", "4/6/2018 17:52"), class = "factor"), V9 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 19L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 
14L, 17L, 18L, 15L), .Label = c("4/6/2018 15:00", "4/6/2018 15:26", 
"4/6/2018 15:32", "4/6/2018 16:01", "4/6/2018 16:10", "4/6/2018 16:12", 
"4/6/2018 16:18", "4/6/2018 16:35", "4/6/2018 16:46", "4/6/2018 17:24", 
"4/6/2018 17:37", "4/6/2018 17:38", "4/6/2018 17:46", "4/6/2018 18:24", 
"4/6/2018 18:46", "4/6/2018 19:21", "4/6/2018 20:14", "4/6/2018 20:35", 
"4/6/2018 21:44"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V8", "V9"), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

***V8 is start time and V9 is end time***.

For this purpose only the start time (V8) matters. 
what is the best way to solve this?

I tried using `if (...) else` statements but can't really get to work.

Comment: Very similar question: add a `labels` argument to the `cut` and you'd be there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875223/r-cut-function-with-posixct-dates-creating-specific-categories-based-on-time-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines. I am assuming that your dates are day/month/year and have called the data frame `df1`.

Your example start times are not very interesting (they all fall into the same quarter), so I used the end times (V9) to illustrate.

You may need to tweak the arguments to `cut` to ensure that the quarter boundaries are as you would like.

The date is the same for all rows in your example but if it were not, you would need to group by date as shown.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  transmute(date_time = dmy_hm(V9), 
            Date = as_date(date_time)) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(quarter = cut(hour(date_time), 
                       breaks = seq(0, 24, 6), 
                       include.lowest = TRUE, 
                       labels = c("00:00 - 05:59", 
                                  "06:00 - 11:59", 
                                  "12:00 - 17:59", 
                                  "18:00 - 23:59"))) %>%
  ungroup()

   date_time           Date       quarter      
   <dttm>              <date>     <fct>        
 1 2018-06-04 15:00:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
 2 2018-06-04 15:32:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
 3 2018-06-04 15:26:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
 4 2018-06-04 16:01:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
 5 2018-06-04 16:35:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
 6 2018-06-04 16:10:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
 7 2018-06-04 16:12:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
 8 2018-06-04 16:46:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
 9 2018-06-04 16:18:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
10 2018-06-04 17:38:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
11 2018-06-04 21:44:00 2018-06-04 18:00 - 23:59
12 2018-06-04 19:21:00 2018-06-04 18:00 - 23:59
13 2018-06-04 17:37:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
14 2018-06-04 17:46:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
15 2018-06-04 17:24:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
16 2018-06-04 18:24:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
17 2018-06-04 20:14:00 2018-06-04 18:00 - 23:59
18 2018-06-04 20:35:00 2018-06-04 18:00 - 23:59
19 2018-06-04 18:46:00 2018-06-04 12:00 - 17:59
```